# Display of product versions?

Tags: nsis

My product has version w.x.y.z. My upgrade of that product has w.x.y.z+1. But the requirement is that before upgrade the fourth field of the version i.e; z should not be checked...i.e; myproduct should not take into consideration the z field.....Please do reply me with an answer.

Comment: Could you please expant you description please? If I understand you want your patch (updated version of product) to update older version when it exists but it should check only the W.X.Y of the product version instead of full W.X.Y.Z?

Comment: Yes thats true and you got me right.... Can you please suggest me what to do and how to exclude the check of the Z of product version....

Answer (score 1):

You can read you App Version from registry and keep it as Variable, then trim it to specific number of chars. Check http://nsis.sourceforge.net/TrimText:_Trim_text_e.g._to_fit_in_a_label

Script below is will work for `ANSI NSIS` if you have such version installed if not, please change `ReadRegStr` accordingly.

```
Name "TrimTest"
OutFile "TrimTest.exe"

!include "TextFunc.nsh"
!include "nsDialogs.nsh"
!include "LogicLib.nsh"
!include "WinMessages.nsh"
!include "WordFunc.nsh"
!insertmacro VersionCompare

Function TrimText
 Exch $R0 ; char
 Exch
 Exch $R1 ; length
 Exch 2
 Exch $R2 ; text
 Push $R3
 Push $R4

 StrLen $R3 $R2
 IntCmp $R3 $R1 Done Done

 StrCpy $R2 $R2 $R1

 StrCpy $R3 0
  IntOp $R3 $R3 + 1
  StrCpy $R4 $R2 1 -$R3
  StrCmp $R4 "" Done
  StrCmp $R4 $R0 0 -3

  IntOp $R3 $R3 + 1
  StrCpy $R4 $R2 1 -$R3
  StrCmp $R4 "" Done
  StrCmp $R4 $R0 -3

  IntOp $R3 $R3 - 1
  StrCpy $R2 $R2 -$R3
  StrCpy $R2 $R2

 Done:
 StrCpy $R0 $R2
  Pop $R4
  Pop $R3
  Pop $R2
  Pop $R1
  Exch $R0 ; output
FunctionEnd

!macro TrimText Text Length Char Var
  Push "${Text}"
  Push "${Length}"
  Push "${Char}"
   Call TrimText
  Pop "${Var}"
!macroend

!define TrimText "!insertmacro TrimText"

Section
  ReadRegStr $0 HKLM "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\NSIS ANSI" "DisplayVersion"
  ${TrimText} $0 7 "-" $R0 
;set max lenght to 7, where only 6 chars are needed, as trimmer will stop on - char
;in your case you will probably want to trim to first . from right side
  ;${TrimText} "string" "max_length" "up_to_char" "$out_var"
  MessageBox MB_ICONEXCLAMATION "Line: $R0"
  ;Input $0 from registry should be "2.46.4-ANSI" if the latest ANSI NSIS is installed
  ;$R0 after trimm will be "Line: 2.46.4"
${VersionCompare} $R0 "2.46.6" $R2
  ${If} $R2 == 1 ;if 2.46.6 is lower that $R0
    MessageBox MB_ICONEXCLAMATION "Your App Version is newer than this version of update"
  ${EndIf}
  ${If} $R2 == 0 ;versions are equal
    MessageBox MB_ICONEXCLAMATION "Your App Version is equal to this version of update"
  ${EndIf}      
  ${If} $R2 == 2 ;if 2.46.6 is higher that $R0
    MessageBox MB_ICONEXCLAMATION "Your App Version is older and will be updated"
  ;here you can write your update section
  ${EndIf}
SectionEnd
```

Comment: Thanks Roben, its working... And another question is that is there any difference between product version numbers 4.1.119 and 4.01.0119?

Comment: That is how they are compared? Does the installer consider both as the same?

Comment: what is the command $strstr... How does that work? for example

Comment: ${StrStr} $1 "$UPGRADEVERS" "$0" is the command.. what is the workflow behind this command? say my upgradevers array is{3.1.123 4.0.112 4.1.119}.... and $0 carries the version 5.0.114.... Roben may be im troubling you... thanks for the help u are doing... Im new to nsis and have to seek somebody's help like you...

Comment: For VersionCompare 4.1.119 is newer than 4.01.0119. You can check that in easy way comparing fake version in script.
`${StrStr}` - description: http://nsis.sourceforge.net/StrStr
So your `$1` result will be empty as there is no `5.0.114` substring in `$UPGRADEVERS`. 
I believe that in this case you should modify TextTrim to trim from right and left. You can also look for different solution e.g. http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Sort_String_2 or Slice http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Slice:_Cut_string_out_of_string or http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Split_strings

Comment: I have posted new solution. If this one works better for you we can delete the first one.

Comment: Hi there. If any of 2 solutions solve your problem please point it up and mark as accepted. TY

Comment: RobeN another issue of the same... My product is installed on windows server the product version it reads as 4.01.0119... Now the product has to be upgraded to 5.00.0134... As mentioned above in Upgradeevers, if i give the substring as 4.1.119 there are no issues for upgrade.. upgrade is going fine... How is the ${strstr} is not finding any change in product versions?

Comment: As I said you cannot use `$StrStr` as `5.00.0134` is not a substring of current version `4.01.0119`. Additionally marking your new version `4.1.119` makes it higher than `4.01.0119`. You have to use my second solution to cut out the middle part of app version and then compare it with your update version (which should use same pattern for version description [with 0s] as application does).

Comment: could you be more precise on that Robe.... Because my product reads as version 4.01.0119 in registry and if i specify 4.1.119 in $upgradevers, the upgrade is going fine... How would this be possible? As you said earlier that there is diff in 4.01.0119 and 4.1.119..... Is there any other that ${strstr} will do apart from joing substring and remaining part of string? Im seriously troubling you alot... Sorry before....

Comment: 4.01.0119 is lower than 4.1.119 so update goes fine. But in fact this is not what you want to achieve. Your updates should base on very same version pattern. If App uses X.XX.XXXX your update has to use X.XX.XXXX as well (should NOT use X.X.XXX pattern). 
As you pointed out that in fact App version is far more complicated (3 parts) but you need only middle part for comparison, my second solution (TrimTest2) cuts middle part of App version and then you can compare it to your update (but still you have to use very same pattern as application does for version marking which is X.XX.XXXX)

Answer (score 1):

In this case this can be a solution (based on http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Sort_String_2).
I have created Test Registry Key just for check with your `{3.1.123 4.0.112 4.1.119}`. Please replace with the one your application uses.

```
Name "TrimTest2"
OutFile "TrimTest2.exe"

!include "TextFunc.nsh"
!include "nsDialogs.nsh"
!include "LogicLib.nsh"
!include "WinMessages.nsh"
!include "WordFunc.nsh"
!insertmacro VersionCompare

Function AdvStrSort
  Exch $0 ; input string
  Exch
  Exch $1 ; count to get part
  Exch
  Exch 2
  Exch $2 ; get ammount of chunks from end
  Exch 2
  Push $3
  Push $4
  Push $5
  Push $6
  Push $7
  StrCpy $0 " $0"
  StrCpy $3 0
  StrCpy $4 0
  loop:
    IntOp $3 $3 - 1
    StrCpy $6 $0 1 $3
    StrCmp $6 "" skip
    StrCmp $6 " " roger ; to change chunk seperators, edit this (" ")
    Goto loop
  roger:
    StrCpy $7 $0 "" $3
    IntOp $4 $4 + 1
    StrCmp $4 $2 0 loop
    StrCmp $1 $2 0 +3
    StrCpy $0 $7
    Goto end
  skip:
    StrCpy $4 0
    StrLen $5 $7
  top:
    IntOp $4 $4 + 1
  loop2:
    IntOp $5 $5 - 1
    StrCpy $3 $7 1 -$5
    StrCmp $3 "" end
    StrCmp $3 " " 0 loop2 ; to change chunk seperators, edit this too (" ")
    StrCmp $4 $1 0 top
    StrCpy $0 $7 -$5
  end:
    StrLen $1 $0
    IntOp $1 $1 - 1
    StrCpy $0 $0 $1 -$1
  Pop $7
  Pop $6
  Pop $5
  Pop $4
  Pop $3
  Pop $2
  Pop $1
  Exch $0 ; output string
FunctionEnd

Section
  ReadRegStr $R1 HKLM "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\UserApplicationName" "Version"
Push 1 ; get text after 1st chunk from string end
 Push 1 ; get 1 chunk before the 1st
  Push "$R1" ; input string (string that has spaces)
    Call AdvStrSort
  Pop $R0
MessageBox MB_ICONEXCLAMATION "Result: $R0"
${VersionCompare} $R0 "5.0.114" $R2
 ;MessageBox MB_ICONEXCLAMATION "Result: $R2"
  ${If} $R2 == 1 ;if 5.0.114 is lower that $R0
    MessageBox MB_ICONEXCLAMATION "Your App Version is newer than this version of update"
  ${EndIf}
  ${If} $R2 == 0 ;versions are equal
    MessageBox MB_ICONEXCLAMATION "Your App Version is equal to this version of update"
  ${EndIf}
  ${If} $R2 == 2 ;if 5.0.114 is higher that $R0
    MessageBox MB_ICONEXCLAMATION "Your App Version is older and will be updated"
  ;here you can write your update section
  ${EndIf}
SectionEnd
```

Comment: hey robe got a solution... Strcpy $0 $0 7... $0 is the version which is read from the uninstall registry of the product installed... Strcpy reads only the first 7 characters of the version... So the fourth field is not read... Thanks for the support you gave... Will get intouch if any other issues...

Comment: If any of my answers did help you, please vote them. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, @user1357950, consider to [`accept the answer`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/179541) if it helped you to resolve your question. You can also vote for the post(s) by clicking on the up arrow above the vote number on the left side of the post ;-) Thanks!

Comment: As you have 16 pts. of reputation score you should be able to vote (15 is the minimum as far as I know).